# using google maps route drawing app crashes

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

when I start onActivityResult I get Intent and my markers are on the google map, but route between markers is not drawn and after second or two my program crashes. My code and log:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == 1) {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                String result = extras.getString("linija");
                setMarkers(result);
            }
            if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

private void setMarkers(String linija) {
    map.clear();
    try {       
        ruta = SAXXMLParser.parse(getAssets().open("linije/linija" +linija+ ".xml"));
        markerPoints.clear();   
        for (int i = 0; i < ruta.size(); i++) {
            final LatLng lokacija = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(ruta.get(
                    i).getLat()), Double.parseDouble(ruta.get(i).getLng()));    
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(lokacija)
                    .title(ruta.get(i).getName())
                    .snippet(ruta.get(i).getAddress())
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.busstop1)));
            markerPoints.add(lokacija);
        }
        if(markerPoints.size() == ruta.size()) 
         {
             for(int j = 1; j < markerPoints.size(); j++) {
                     int i = j - 1;
                     LatLng origin = markerPoints.get(i);
                     LatLng dest = markerPoints.get(j);
                    // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
                    String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);
                    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
                        // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
                    downloadTask.execute(url);
                 }                      
             }                   
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin,LatLng dest){

    // Origin of route
    String str_origin = "origin="+origin.latitude+","+origin.longitude;
    // Destination of route
    String str_dest = "destination="+dest.latitude+","+dest.longitude; 
    // Sensor enabled
    String sensor = "sensor=false";

    // Waypoints
    String waypoints = "";
    for(int i=2;i<markerPoints.size();i++){
        LatLng point  = (LatLng) markerPoints.get(i);
        if(i==2)
            waypoints = "waypoints=";
        waypoints += point.latitude + "," + point.longitude + "|";
    }

    // Building the parameters to the web service
    String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor+"&"+waypoints; 
    // Output format
    String output = "json";
    // Building the url to the web service
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters;

    return url;
}

private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try{
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);
            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url 
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            // Connecting to url 
            urlConnection.connect();
            // Reading data from url 
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));
            StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";
            while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                    sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
    }finally{
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return data;
 }

// Fetches data from url passed
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{          

    // Downloading data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

        // For storing data from web service
        String data = "";

        try{
            // Fetching the data from web service
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
        }
        return data;        
    }

    // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
    // doInBackground()
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {           
        super.onPostExecute(result);            

        ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

        // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
        parserTask.execute(result);

    }       
}

/** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> >{

    // Parsing the data in non-ui thread        
    @Override
    protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        JSONObject jObject; 
        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;                     

        try{
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
            DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

            // Starts parsing data
            routes = parser.parse(jObject);    
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return routes;
    }

    // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {

        ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
        PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;

        // Traversing through all the routes
        for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
            points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
            lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

            // Fetching i-th route
            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

            // Fetching all the points in i-th route
            for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j);                 

                double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng); 

                points.add(position);                       
            }

            // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
            lineOptions.addAll(points);
            lineOptions.width(2);
            lineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);              
        }

        // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
        map.addPolyline(lineOptions);                           
    }           
}
```

I just copy/paste what I think is important, so maybe one bracket is missing, there are no errors in eclipse...
LOGCAT:

```
08-28 22:03:57.451: E/AndroidRuntime(5248): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-28 22:03:57.451: E/AndroidRuntime(5248): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-28 22:03:57.451: E/AndroidRuntime(5248):     at ova.<init>(Unknown Source)
08-28 22:03:57.451: E/AndroidRuntime(5248):     at oux.b(Unknown Source)
08-28 22:03:57.451: E/AndroidRuntime(5248):     at oux.a(Unknown Source)
08-28 22:03:57.451: E/AndroidRuntime(5248):     at oyf.a(Unknown Source)
08-28 22:03:57.451: E/AndroidRuntime(5248):     at grl.onTransact(SourceFile:137)
08-28 22:03:57.451: E/AndroidRuntime(5248):     at     
android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:297)
08-28 22:03:57.451: E/AndroidRuntime(5248):     at  
com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$a$a.addPolyline(Unknown Source)
08-28 22:03:57.451: E/AndroidRuntime(5248):     at 
com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addPolyline(Unknown Source)
08-28 22:03:57.451: E/AndroidRuntime(5248):     at   
com.project.busme.MainActivity$ParserTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:342)
08-28 22:03:57.451: E/AndroidRuntime(5248):     at 
com.project.busme.MainActivity$ParserTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
08-28 22:03:57.451: E/AndroidRuntime(5248):     at 
android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
08-28 22:03:57.451: E/AndroidRuntime(5248):     at  
android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
08-28 22:03:57.451: E/AndroidRuntime(5248):     at 
android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
08-28 22:03:57.451: E/AndroidRuntime(5248):     at  
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-28 22:03:57.451: E/AndroidRuntime(5248):     at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-28 22:03:57.451: E/AndroidRuntime(5248):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
08-28 22:03:57.451: E/AndroidRuntime(5248):     at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-28 22:03:57.451: E/AndroidRuntime(5248):     at  
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-28 22:03:57.451: E/AndroidRuntime(5248):     at   
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
08-28 22:03:57.451: E/AndroidRuntime(5248):     at  
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
08-28 22:03:57.451: E/AndroidRuntime(5248):     at 
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I also get this, but only for HUUUGE trips, so I'm guessing the route polyline is to big, so when you decode it you lose to much memory on that. For me it also said this:

```
" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 159624 byte allocation with 554952 free bytes; failed due to fragmentation (largest possible contiguous allocation 57448 bytes)"
```

I do not know a fix for this, but am looking for a optimisation in order to use less memory. If you figure out how to escape this, please let me know.